# ActionController::UnknownHttpMethod: CONNECT

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, web-hosting

I get the above error message in my log file sometimes, `originates from actionpack-x.y.z/action_controller/request.rb`.

What should I do in order to prevent a route on anything other than HTTP methods like `get, put, delete` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`HTTP CONNECT` requests are generally coming from proxy server or crawlers.

We can tackle the above issue by adding a filter in web server, so that those requests are denied. So it is more about tuning the web server than doing in the ruby application.

Example: http://www.webhostingtalk.com/showthread.php?t=461915